# TortoiseSVN caused red circle with exclamation mark on folder icon

Tags: android, tortoisesvn

I was just recently introduced to TortoiseSVN and I uploaded my Android project to the repository. Made several changes to the project which I ended up not liking so I re-imported the old version from the repository back to my computer. Now I have several folders within the project showing a red circle with an exclamation mark inside of it ontop of the folder icon. Does anyone know what this means or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that you changed the content of that folder. Commit, and the icon will go green again. Should also work if you revert everything.

Comment: I commited and all but one of them went away. My app still works fine but I'm planning to add a Log In screen and encrypt all the data and I don't want it to be corrupted if I need to export it back to my machine again.